# Здесь: туристической или туристской?

Tags: грамотная-речь, синонимы, паронимы

> И хорошо в «Нормандии» не только летом, что очевидно, когда весь город
>   живёт **лихорадочной туристической жизнью**, но и в межсезонье –
>   ранней весной, когда все вокруг в цвету яблоневых деревьев...

Думается, что жизнь - туристская.

Comment: А что очевидно - что летом хорошо или очевидно только когда? Жить туристической жизнью - летом все лихорадочно разъезжаются (в городах заполярья именно так), и хорошо от того, что спокойнее? Может, просто город туристов принимает или хорошо в летний туристический сезон?

Comment: Спасибо, Саша! Перечитывала несколько раз, спотыкаючись, но так и не поняла, где закавыка. Шлём автору на раздумья.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Словарь трудностей русского языка**](https://difficulties.academic.ru/178/%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9):
**туристский** и **туристический**

Прилагательное **туристский** образовано непосредственно от слова турист и имеет значение "относящийся к туристу (туристам)": *туристская палатка, туристский лагерь, туристские ботинки.*
Сюда бы я отнесла и словосочетание "туристская жизнь" (в палатке, на колёсах, дикарём, в кемпинге, на комфортабельном теплоходе...).

Прилагательное **туристический** связано по смыслу в первую очередь с существительным туризм и значит "относящийся к туризму": *туристическое бюро, туристическая виза, туристическая поездка, туристические буклеты.*
Город — не турист. Город *приспосабливается* и неистово *организуется* на определённый период, поэтому он *живёт лихорадочной **туристической** жизнью*, подчиняя себя интересам туризма (а не отдельного туриста).
Я вижу так.